# How to open a window(poup) on mobile browser from inside a webview using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webview

I have a web page, which if loaded inside a webview, then the page should reload in a mobile web browser instead of inside the webview. 
Basically I want to send the user to a browser from the webview.
Is this possible using javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 0):

> Here is example for dialog or popup in webview :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
alert.setTitle("Title here");

WebView wv = new WebView(this);
wv.loadUrl("http:\\www.google.com");
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);

        return true;
    }
});

alert.setView(wv);
alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
alert.show();
```