# Open URL in a mobile browser from the inApp webview using Javascript

Tags: javascript, inappbrowser, mobile-browser, flutterwebviewplugin

Assuming that I called a webpage using a Flutter webview plugin. The webpage code are as follows :

```
<button onclick="window.open('https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=60175XXXX','_system');"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i> Whatsapp</button>
```

When I clicked on the button, it redirects to ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME because the link pointed to whatsapp:// , not https:// .

I am trying not to adjust the Flutter code, by not following the [Android WebView err_unknown_url_scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693263/android-webview-err-unknown-url-scheme) .
I just want to use Javascript inside the webpage to open the mobile browser.

Already tried to use '_blank' or target='_system', but it doesn't work.

```
"window.open('https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=60175XXXX','_blank');"

<a href="https://www.google.com/" target='_system'>...</a>
```

Any helps? Thank you.

My question might be similar with this one, but the answer doesn't help much.
[How to open a window(poup) on mobile browser from inside a webview using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915263/how-to-open-a-windowpoup-on-mobile-browser-from-inside-a-webview-using-javascr)

Comment: I am not sure about the Flutter. But in React Native we use linking / deep link to do that. Maybe you can check for that

Comment: Thank you sir. I ended up adjusting the Flutter code. Already tried to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/35119754/7228432 , but it doesn't work.